# GROUP BY WHERE range AND const ref without temporary

Tags: mysql, mariadb, tokudb

A really basic table containing quotes on instruments across multiple exchanges leveraging the TokuDB storage engine:

```
CREATE TABLE `quotes` (
  `ticker` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` time(3) NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(7,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `size` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `exchange` char(3) NOT NULL,
  KEY `best_price` (`ticker`,`timestamp`,`exchange`,`price`),
  KEY `best_size` (`exchange`,`ticker`,`price`,`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=TokuDB
```

Whenever I query for best price across all exchanges it always uses a temporary table.  The presence of `exchange` and `price` in the index only appears to produce an index scan being equivalent to a clustered key on `(ticker, timestamp)` in TokuDB.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT max(price),exchange
FROM quotes
WHERE
  ticker="A" AND
  timestamp BETWEEN "15:15:22.328961" AND "15:17:22.328961"
GROUP BY exchange
ORDER BY NULL \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: quotes
         type: range
possible_keys: best_price
          key: best_price
      key_len: 9
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2690
        Extra: Using where; Using index; Using temporary
```

Is it possible to define a configuration that would not use a temporary table?  This appears only possible when dropping the `timestamp` article:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT max(price),exchange
FROM quotes
WHERE
  ticker="A"
GROUP BY exchange
ORDER BY NULL \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: quotes
         type: range
possible_keys: best_price
          key: best_size
      key_len: 7
          ref: NULL
         rows: 96
        Extra: Using where; Using index for group-by
```

Example output from best price query:

```
+------------+----------+
| max(price) | exchange |
+------------+----------+
|      41.06 | BTY      |
|      41.06 | DEA      |
|      41.07 | NYS      |
|      41.07 | THM      |
|      41.06 | PSE      |
|      41.07 | BAT      |
|      41.06 | DEX      |
|      41.06 | BOS      |
|      41.06 | ADC      |
|      41.06 | XPH      |
+------------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And the bottleneck (3ms) is processing each individual row in the time range:

```
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000071 |
| checking permissions | 0.000005 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000016 |
| After opening tables | 0.000006 |
| System lock          | 0.000014 |
| Table lock           | 0.000002 |
| After table lock     | 0.000005 |
| init                 | 0.000038 |
| optimizing           | 0.000024 |
| statistics           | 0.000155 |
| preparing            | 0.000028 |
| executing            | 0.000003 |
| Copying to tmp table | 0.000031 |
| Copying to tmp table | 0.003381 |
| Sending data         | 0.000017 |
| end                  | 0.000004 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000020 |
| end                  | 0.000002 |
| query end            | 0.000005 |
| closing tables       | 0.000005 |
| freeing items        | 0.000006 |
| updating status      | 0.000011 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000002 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

The time range contains 2316 rows, broken down by exchange:

```
+----------+----------+
| exchange | count(*) |
+----------+----------+
| ADC      |       71 |
| BAT      |      298 |
| BOS      |      129 |
| BTY      |      266 |
| DEA      |      153 |
| DEX      |       60 |
| NYS      |      530 |
| PSE      |      325 |
| THM      |      453 |
| XPH      |       31 |
+----------+----------+
```

I've tried the *crazy* and added every permutation of covering index and MariaDB cannot find a better key.  Are there other databases I should be looking at instead?

Example data set for time range and ticker symbol: http://pastebin.com/b5RcTXAs

Comment: What's `ric`? I don't see that column in your table?

Comment: Wow... this is a really interesting question. Okay, so this is going to sound ridiculous but can you give something a (admittedly long) shot? Can you try removing the ORDER BY NULL portion of your query? I know what you're thinking there and I don't really believe this will help... but I want to rule out the possibility of a bug. This is an interesting question... gonna be thinking about this one for a while.

Comment: @evanv removing `ORDER BY` yields `Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort` as expected.

Comment: Hmmm.  With InnoDB, and with ORDER BY NULL, and with the covering index `(ticker, timestamp, exchange, price)` I get `Using where; Using index; Using temporary` without the filesort. And the result set isn't in order. Taking out `ORDER  BY NULL` puts back the `Using filesort`.  `Using index` tells me the covering index did its job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is all about optimisation.  MySQL has chosen to use a temporary table because it is considered more sensible than using the indexes to fetch each exchange.  If one uses a clustered index across `exchange,ticker,timestamp` then the query can operate without a temporary:

```
MariaDB [trth]> explain SELECT min(ask_price),exchange
FROM quotes
USE INDEX (exchange_ticker_timestamp)
WHERE exchange IN ("NYS","BOS","CIN","ADC","DEX","DEA","MID","PSE","THM","WCB","BAT","XPH","BTY") AND 
   ticker="A" AND
   timestamp BETWEEN "15:15:22.328961" AND "15:17:22.328961"
GROUP BY exchange
ORDER BY NULL \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: quotes
         type: range
possible_keys: exchange_ticker_timestamp
          key: exchange_ticker_timestamp
      key_len: 10
          ref: NULL
         rows: 2589
        Extra: Using where; Using index

MariaDB [trth]> show profile; 
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000079 |
| checking permissions | 0.000006 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000014 |
| After opening tables | 0.000011 |
| System lock          | 0.000014 |
| Table lock           | 0.000003 |
| After table lock     | 0.000005 |
| init                 | 0.000043 |
| optimizing           | 0.000019 |
| statistics           | 0.000234 |
| preparing            | 0.000027 |
| executing            | 0.000008 |
| Sorting result       | 0.000002 |
| Sending data         | 0.002985 |
| end                  | 0.000006 |
| query end            | 0.000010 |
| closing tables       | 0.000006 |
| freeing items        | 0.000007 |
| updating status      | 0.000138 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000004 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

Compare with a temporary table grouping:

```
MariaDB [trth]> explain SELECT min(ask_price),exchange
FROM quotes
WHERE ticker="A" AND
   timestamp BETWEEN "15:15:22.328961" AND "15:17:22.328961"
GROUP BY exchange
ORDER BY NULL \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: quotes
         type: range
possible_keys: ticker_timestamp
          key: ticker_timestamp
      key_len: 9
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1515
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary

MariaDB [trth]> show profile;  
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000091 |
| checking permissions | 0.000009 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000037 |
| After opening tables | 0.000009 |
| System lock          | 0.000052 |
| Table lock           | 0.000004 |
| After table lock     | 0.000009 |
| init                 | 0.000049 |
| optimizing           | 0.000025 |
| statistics           | 0.000144 |
| preparing            | 0.000039 |
| executing            | 0.000003 |
| Copying to tmp table | 0.000040 |
| Copying to tmp table | 0.004674 |
| Sending data         | 0.000020 |
| end                  | 0.000003 |
| removing tmp table   | 0.000015 |
| end                  | 0.000003 |
| query end            | 0.000004 |
| closing tables       | 0.000006 |
| freeing items        | 0.000006 |
| updating status      | 0.000204 |
| cleaning up          | 0.000004 |
+----------------------+----------+
```

What is interesting to note here is that the first query scans more rows but is executed faster than the second.